# Python: Pyppeteer with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pyppeteer

I was doing some tests and I wonder if the script below is running asynchronously?

```
# python test.py  It took 1.3439464569091797 seconds.
```

**31 (sites) x 1.34 = 41.54s** - so it's a few seconds less but in theory it should take only as long as the longest request?

```
# python test.py  It took 28.129364728927612 seconds.
```

Perhaps opening a browser is not async here and I should use [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor) for this?

```
# cat test.py 
import asyncio
import time

from pyppeteer import launch
from urllib.parse import urlparse

WEBSITE_LIST = [
    'http://envato.com',
    'http://amazon.co.uk',
    'http://amazon.com',
    'http://facebook.com',
    'http://google.com',
    'http://google.fr',
    'http://google.es',
    'http://google.co.uk',
    'http://internet.org',
    'http://gmail.com',
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://github.com',
    'http://heroku.com',
    'http://djangoproject.com',
    'http://rubyonrails.org',
    'http://basecamp.com',
    'http://trello.com',
    'http://yiiframework.com',
    'http://shopify.com',
    'http://airbnb.com',
    'http://instagram.com',
    'http://snapchat.com',
    'http://youtube.com',
    'http://baidu.com',
    'http://yahoo.com',
    'http://live.com',
    'http://linkedin.com',
    'http://yandex.ru',
    'http://netflix.com',
    'http://wordpress.com',
    'http://bing.com',
]

start = time.time()

async def fetch(url):
    browser = await launch(headless=True, args=['--no-sandbox'])
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(f'{url}', {'waitUntil': 'load'})
    await page.screenshot({'path': f'img/{urlparse(url)[1]}.png'})
    await browser.close()

async def run():
    tasks = []

    for url in WEBSITE_LIST:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    #print(responses)

#asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(fetch('http://yahoo.com'))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)

print(f'It took {time.time()-start} seconds.')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to pyppeteer source code, it is using [subprocess](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/blob/31039b6952b079d0c52a57b63400c869e910d811/pyppeteer/launcher.py#L132) without pipes to manage Chromium processes, and [websockets](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/blob/31039b6952b079d0c52a57b63400c869e910d811/pyppeteer/connection.py#L39) to communicate, therefore it is async.

You have 31 sites, then you'll have 31+1 processes. So unless you have a CPU with 32 cores (there might also be threads, system processes, locks, hyper-threading and all different factors infecting the result, so this is just an imprecise example), it won't be fully executed **in parallel**. Therefore, the bottleneck I think is CPU opening browsers, rendering web pages and dumping into images. Using executor won't help.

However, it is still async. That means, your Python process is not blocked, you can still run other code or wait for network results **concurrently**. It is only that when the CPU is fully loaded by other processes, it becomes harder for the Python process to "steal" CPU time.