# Should I call my async function in another process/thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am screenshotting several thousand web pages with pyppeteer. I discovered by accident, that running the same script in 2 open terminals doubles the output I get. I tested this by opening up to 6 terminals and running the script and I was able to get up to 6 times the performance.

I am considering using `loop.run_in_executor` to run the script in multiple processes or threads from a main program.

Is this the right call or is am I hitting some IO/CPU limit in my script?

Here is how I'm thinking of doing it. I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

async def blocking_io():
    # File operations (such as logging) can block the
    # event loop: run them in a thread pool.
    with open('/dev/urandom', 'rb') as f:
        return f.read(100)

async def cpu_bound():
    # CPU-bound operations will block the event loop:
    # in general it is preferable to run them in a
    # process pool.
    return sum(i * i for i in range(10 ** 7))

def wrap_blocking_io():
    return asyncio.run(blocking_io())

def wrap_cpu_bound():
    return asyncio.run(cpu_bound())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # Options:
    # 1. Run in the default loop's executor:
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(
        None, wrap_blocking_io)
    print('default thread pool', result)
    # 2. Run in a custom thread pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, wrap_blocking_io)
        print('custom thread pool', result)
    # 3. Run in a custom process pool:
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as pool:
        result = await loop.run_in_executor(
            pool, wrap_cpu_bound)
        print('custom process pool', result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: there's nothing particularly bad in using `loop.run_in_executor` within your async code

Comment: Is it okay to use it to run an asynchronous function? I've shared an example of how I'd do this. I don't think there's anything blocking in my code.

Answer (score 1):

> I tested this by opening up to 6 terminals and running the script and
>   I was able to get up to 6 times the performance.

Since `pyppeteer` is already asynchronous I presume you just don't run multiple browsers parallely and that's why you have increased output when you run multiple processes.

To run some coroutines concurrently ("in parallel") you usually use something like [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). Does you code have it? If answer is no, check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51041482/1113207) - this is how you should run multiple jobs:

```
responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

---

If you already using `asyncio.gather` consider to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier to understand what happens.